# Execute multiple python codes in shell

Tags: python-3.x, shell

I have multiple codes separated in different files. I'm used to copy paste them in ipython3 to execute.

This way i can use a function1 (example) that is in code1 when i exec code2 on ipython.

But i want to do this in shell script now, and when i try to execute code2, it says that function1 doesn't exists. Probably shell executes each code in separated ipython terminals.

```
cd Documents/comprasnet_platform_00/cotacao/auth/mods
ipython3 code1.py
ipython3 ../../init/mods/code2.py
```

Comment: adding a line `import code1` in `code2.py` doesn't work?